# How to pass array of custom objects in request of soap service using ksoap2 in android

Tags: android, wcf, soap, android-ksoap2

I want to pass an array of objects in the request of a WCF service using ksoap2 in android.

My xml request looks like:

```
<tem:bookItems>  
    <res:bookItem>
       <res:name>"abcd"</res:name>
       <res:price>150</res:price>
    </res:bookItem>
    <res:bookItem>
       <res:name>"efgh"</res:name>
       <res:price>250</res:price>
    </res:bookItem>
</tem:bookItems>
```

I was not being able to find a proper answer and I am stuck completely. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be interested in `org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable` interface in ksoap2.

For any array object you can create `public abstract class LiteralArrayVector extends Vector implements KvmSerializable`.

`LiteralArrayVector` ideally should have following:

1. to register your soap envelope object

   `public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope, String namespace, String name)`

   `envelope.addMapping(namespace, name, this.getClass());
   registerElementClass(envelope, namespace);`
2. Define `private void registerElementClass(SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope, String namespace)` with `envelope.addMapping(namespace, "", elementClass);`

   `Class elementClass = getElementClass();`

   // In concrete class of `LiteralArrayVector`, say, `ArrayOfBookItem`, override `getElementClass()` of `super`, to return your `BookItem` element class

   Something like:

   `protected Class getElementClass() {
       return new BookItem().getClass();
   }`

and `getItemDescriptor` to return name of your element, "BookItem"

3. `getPropertyInfo()` of `KvmSerializable` should be overridden such that `PropertyInfo` should have name and type of your `BookItem`

   `public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
       info.name = getItemDescriptor();
       info.type = getElementClass();
   }`

`ArrayOfBookItem` should override `register` of `LiteralArrayVector` such that it calls `super(...)` and has `new BookItem().register(envelope)`.

When I say `register(...)` I mean some way to add mapping for your elements to `SoapSerializationEnvelope`

```
public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope) {
    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "BookItem", this.getClass());
}
```

See if it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My soap service is expecting 'List<bookItem> bookItems'. So will the above code serve the purpose and also if you can please share the complete code. Not able to catch the complete steps.Trying to consolidate the steps mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search and investigstion, found out a  very simple way to do the above. I just changed my service to accept an array of JSON object instead of list of objects. It works like charm and issue got resolved with in minutes.
here is the service request modified,

---

```
<tem:bookItems>[{"name": "abcd", "price": "150"}, { "name": "efgh", "price": "250"} ]</tem:bookItems>
```

And from application we pass object like,

```
     JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

            JSONObject bookObj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                bookObj.put("name","abcd");
                bookObj.put("price","150");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jsonArr.put(bookObj);
        }
        //the below string will be passed to service
        String bookItems = jsonArr.toString();
```